# Error could not find libjava.so when running java binary

Tags: java

I uninstalled  jdk 1.8 and installed JDK 1.7 on my ubuntu but when I am trying to run java ,I am getting the following Error:

```
sana@sana:~$ java -version
Error: could not find libjava.so
Error: Could not find Java SE Runtime Environment.
```

Comment: Make sure jdk1.7 bin directory is in your path `echo $PATH`

Comment: I believe jdk1.7 isn't supported anymore. What is the output of `which java` and `which javac`?

Comment: sana@sana:~$ echo $PATH
/opt/maven/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/local/java/jre1.7.0_45/bin:/usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_45/bin

Comment: sana@sana:~$ which java
/usr/bin/java

Comment: sana@sana:~$ which javac
/usr/bin/javac

Comment: And what about output of `locate libjava.so`?

Comment: I have no output

Comment: sana@sana:~$ locate libjava.so
sana@sana:~$

Comment: In that case try re-installation of jdk

Comment: I tried, but again I get this error

Comment: All the info in these comments _should be in the Question_ with an [edit].

Answer (score -2):

Try rebooting your computer after installing it and try again.

Or you could have a problem similar to this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25954348/error-could-not-find-libjava-so-error-could-not-find-java-2-runtime-environme

One of the poster mentions he has 2 versions installed: "I encounter this issue before. It turns out there are 2 javac program sitting on my machine. They are in /usr/bin/javac and /bin/javac. My system used the /bin/javac one. The right path for me is /usr/bin/javac. Removing /bin/javac helped"